# How can I resize an image in a react-paper card.cover to fit the height?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Cover source={{ uri: props.source.uri }}
              resizeMode={`cover`} style={{flexDirection: 'column'}}/>
  <Card.Content>
    {/* <Title>Card title</Title> */}
    <Text>Card content</Text>
  </Card.Content>
</Card>
```

And am trying to scale the `Card.Cover` so that each card is not the same height - but rather it depends on the image dimensions. Currently, all of the cards have the same height and width. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use

```
Image.getSize(uri, success, [failure]);
```

to get and set the height? [Image.getSize](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.html#getsize)

Or you could try like this:

```
Image.resolveAssetSource(require("uri")).height
```

In your code

```
<Card.Cover source={{ uri: props.source.uri }} resizeMode={`cover`} style={{flexDirection: 'column',height:Image.resolveAssetSource(require(props.source.uri)).height}}/>
```